# What does this line of code do? [Newbie]

Tags: c, cs50

```
int main(void)
{
    string n = GetString();
    if(n!=NULL){
        for(int i=0, j=strlen(n); i<j; i++){
            if(!isalpha(n[i-1]) && isalpha(n[i])){
                printf("%c", toupper(n[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> if(!isalpha(name[i-1]) && isalpha(name[i]))

how can this line be explained to a new starter?(by the way the code works properly on harvard's cs50 ide)

Comment: It invokes [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: break it into it's component pieces and run it in a debugger - then you will have explained it to yourself (and become less of a noob).  And no, it does not run properly (unless you define undefined behavior as your intended result)!

Comment: @KevinDTimm it works on harvard's CS50 IDE.

Comment: @alemst11 The code is wrong, but at least it's clear what it's trying to do, if the previous letter is not an alphabetical character and the current is, print the current capitalized. However as has already been pointed out, if n is not null then the behaviour is undefined as `!isalpha(n[i-1])` will evaluate to `!isalpha(n[-1])` which is out of bounds. NOTE: UB doesn't mean it can not and will not work, it may sometimes appear to work but it's horrible to debug when it goes wrong, and most of the time (in my experience) , it will.

Comment: As @George pointed out - the code is wrong. The fact the your IDE allows it is not a reason to believe that it is correct.  I'm extremely leery that there is a `string` data type (c doesn't have one).  I would recommend that you post a [mcve] so that the program can be properly critiqued.

Comment: @KevinDTimm In Line 52 of `cs50.h` it says `typedef char* string;`.

Comment: And how would I know that?  The posted code has no reference to `cs50.h`  Without a [mcve], there's no way to know what the user has done. Note too that OP still argues that this is 'working' code even when he's been told it invokes UB.

Comment: got it working now. changed the line i was asking of. @ventiseis thanks.

Comment: @alemst11 I you are still looking for an answert, please update your question with your changed code.

Comment: Hasn't this been asked a couple of hours before ?

Answer (score 1):

The code is attempting to find every occurrence of a non-alphabetic character in the array `n` followed by an alphabetic character and, in each one, print that alphabetic character in upper case.

The problem is, since `i` starts with the value of `0`, the code has undefined behaviour in the first iteration since it accesses a character before the start of the array.

The code might seem to work properly under cs50, but that is just happenstance.   One feature of undefined behaviour is that it is not required to produce any error, or any unexpected results.    But that doesn't make it right.  It simply means that it did not produce an observable symptom in some set of circumstances.

Note:  for sake of discussion, I am assuming `string` is a pointer to `char`, and that `GetString()` returns the address of the first character in an array of `char`.